# Setting size of table for records retrieved from csv and using 2nd column as row ID/key?

Tags: c#, csv, create-table

First of all I am new-beginner, but I need to develop skills fast to support an application I want to create, so please chip in and don't assume I know the libraries/methods you are referring to so please be very specific.

I try to describe the full context, so you know where I am heading.

In the code below I just read headers and records from a csv-file and present the first 10 lines in the console (to get a visual - the read() line will be deleted once I import the 1500 lines file) - but I cannot find a command to count lines (FieldCount), but do I really need to count the lines or can the table or array be dynamic and do the count when I get the records without killing performance?

Table size is not expected to exceed 20 columns by 5000 lines

1. My intention is to get the records from the csv-file
2. store them in a global data table (all as strings for now), where it is the second column that holds the unique row ID and where I can add more columns as start to manipulate data
   3.Following this I will create a new table that counts the found occurences from various columns in the first table.
   The new table must be stored so I can present in another .net web-app.

All help is really appreciated, preferably by not adding too many libraries

```
using System;  
using System.IO;  
using CsvHelper;  
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO;  


namespace Interpreter01  
{  
class Program  
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
   // open the file "INDOM01-10.csv" which is a CSV file with headers
        ICsvReader ICsv =
        new CsvHelper.CsvReader(new StreamReader(@"c:\AD\INDOM01-10.csv", true));

        {

            ICsv.ReadHeader();

            int FieldCount = 10; 
//I cannot find a command to count the number of lines in the csv-file
//So I insert 10 to continue the coding

            string[] headers = ICsv.FieldHeaders;

            while (ICsv.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < FieldCount; i++)
                    Console.Write(string.Format("{0} = {1};",
                                  headers[i], ICsv[i]));

                Console.WriteLine(headers); 
                Console.ReadKey(); //just inserted to visually check data 
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```